# Eclipse closes automatically

Tags: 12.10, eclipse

Eclipse in my Ubuntu 12.10 closes automatically. It happened a lots of time. When I executed eclipse from terminal, it gave me following messages.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
Refresh!!
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
Refresh!!
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
```

I've no idea what is causing this problem.

**What is `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` and how to load it?**

Also if any plugins installed is causing problem, I've installed following plugins.

- WindowsBuilder Pro
- Spring IDE
- EGit
- m2eclipse
- DBViewer
- Dali Java Persistence Tools

I can't attach whole `.log` file in this question, so I've put it in [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/TheKojuEffect/4996082#file-eclipseautocloseerror-log)

**UPDATE**

Recently, I was having automatic closing of Eclipse and I got some hint that `Eclipse` closes automatically when I switch to different workspaces but not always.

Any idea, why this couldn't happening?

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be in the error. check the third SLF4J and it tells you to refer to a website (http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder).

The website tells us:

> This error is reported when the org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder class could not be loaded into memory. This happens when no appropriate SLF4J binding could be found on the class path. Placing one (and only one) of slf4j-nop.jar, slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar on the class path should solve the problem.
>
> As of SLF4J version 1.6, in the absence of a binding, SLF4J will default to a no-operation (NOP) logger implementation.
>
> You can download SLF4J bindings from the project download page.

I suggest you go to the website I linked above and try what the website says :) It helpfully gives you a link to the download page.

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

I thought I would add this in here, as I noticed in the original question it asks what this StaticLoggerBinder is.

Effectively, it's used by SLF4J to assist with what kind of logging you do for your project. http://www.slf4j.org/index.html being the main site. You'll see there's a good number of projects that depend on SLF4J.

What is logging? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/logging/index.html.

This has been good reading, so thanks for the question!

Comment: how to keep the downloaded package to the classpath?

Comment: You find the download, save either the .tar.gz file or .zip file wherever you want to and open it. Find file you want and extract that to the class path. If you are more comfortable with GUIs, use the .zip file.

Comment: I am little confused here. I'm not familiar with classpath for eclipse. Does that mean classpath for any project opened in eclipse?

Comment: Whilst it seems oddly worded, I would assume this means the project directory.

Comment: The first three lines of messages `SLF4J` in Terminal appears even when I open eclipse  with empty workspace.
May be the `.log` file will help debugging this. So, I've attached .log file in question.
Please Check it out.

Comment: Those three starting lines are how I came to that website, have you tried the fix I mentioned? sounds like you need one of the files :)

Comment: As I mention in previous comment, there are those errors even when I open eclipse with empty workspace. Then What is the classpath for  project directory?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828719/failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder-which-classpath - appears this is more to do with the POM.xml

Comment: I don't have any dependency for `slf4j` in my POM.xml. Anyway, I'll try.